# $mdToast.simple is not a function

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

$mdToast.simple is not a function

[Codepin](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XpvdMg)

```
$scope.showToast = function() {
 var pinTo = $scope.getToastPosition();
  $mdToast.show(
    $mdToast.simple()
      .textContent('Saved!')
      .position(pinTo )
      .hideDelay(2000)
   );
 };
```

Put as much of my code in here as I could, still same issue.. is it the order of things or a version? I have rearranged and tried many things but still getting the same error. Checked this site and git issues for similar fixes but looks like OP never comes back with what works.

It also seems like it is trying to get the function from angular.js rather than angular-material.js?

Thanks all

***The Fix***

My Code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['firebase', 'ngMaterial', 'ngRoute']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope',
 function($scope, $mdToast, $firebaseObject, $rootScope) {
```

Working code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['firebase', 'ngMaterial', 'ngRoute']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdToast', '$rootScope', 
 function($scope, $mdToast, $firebaseObject, $rootScope) {
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `$mdToast` as a dependency to your controller? `app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdToast', '$firebaseObject', '$rootScope', 
    function($scope, $mdToast, $firebaseObject, $rootScope)`

Comment: @AlexSzabó yes that was the issue, it is not in their docs like that on the Angular Material demos :/ Thank you for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was you are missing the  `'$mdToast', '$firebaseObject', in the dependency injection

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdToast', '$firebaseObject', '$rootScope', 
    function($scope, $mdToast, $firebaseObject, $rootScope) {
```

[WORKING CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/sajeetharan/pen/vgoVeV)

Comment: Uggh thank you. I see what you mean, and now that works, but how come that isn't in the docs? [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/toast) they only put it as a function parameter 'angular.module('toastDemo1', ['ngMaterial'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $mdToast) {'

Comment: it is there in the angular docs, read about dependency injection. mark as answer if it has helped

Comment: Do you see it in the above docs I linked to? under JS they don't place it in both spots. Also in your codepin I had to add it 'app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', ***'$mdToast'***, '$rootScope', function($scope, $mdToast, $firebaseObject, $rootScope) {' if you want to update that for others. Can't believe I wasted so much time for a simple solution Lol